# Android Progress Bar appear and hide

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a progress bar and I do not want to incorporate a numerical value to show the loading of some content. I just want that the ProgressBar should appear, animate and then go away.

I used:

```
public void buttonClick(View v){
      ProgressBar mProgress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.my_progress);
      mProgress.setVisibility(VISIBLE);     //line 1..

      //loading data from web... takes time

      mProgress.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);   //line 2..
}
```

but when I run this code, both line 1 and line 2 executes, but the UI changes afterwards, which is not desired. I want that when the button is clicked, the progress bar should appear and when the data is downloaded from the web the progress bar should disappear.

I tried setting the visibility from another thread, but it didn't work as UI changes are not allowed in other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You download your data in AsyncTask right? Put this code

```
private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // download your data here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way implement it by using an `AsyncTask`

**MyTask.java**

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    MyTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do your task here
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

You can start the task like this:

```
public void buttonClick(View v){
    new MyTask(YourActivity.this).execute();
}
```

You can modify the `AsyncTask` accordingly to retrieve the result.

Hope it helps. :)